# Where can I get CommonCrypto / CommonCrypto file from?

Tags: ios, swift, commoncrypto

I have a problem with importing `CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto` or `CommonCrypto/CommonDigest`. I need a SHA256 for my `Swift` code.

I found `CommonCrypto` github site in Cocoapods.

https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit

So I have downloaded the file from above.
But I'm getting errors about `ARC` (I have added Bridging-Header like other tutorials do.)
The header file's name is `NSData+CommonCrypto.h` and `NSData+CommonCrypto.m`.
It's not a `CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto` or `CommonCrypto/CommonDigest`
Where can I download and get the exact file `CommonCrypto` for SHA256?

Answer (score 7):

No additional files are required. You need a [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122) first of all, which you already have but for those who don't the easiest way to achieve this is to add an Objective-C file to your project and to accept when it offers to create a bridging header. You can then either import the whole of CommonCrypto (thanks @zaph - see comments) to the bridging header:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

Or the constituent parts:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonSymmetricKeywrap.h>
```

You can now use CommonCrypto in Swift. For example code [see here](http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/resurrecting-commoncrypto-in-swift-for.html).

**Edit**

In Xcode 10 a bridging header is no longer required to import CommonCrypto in Swift. You can simply use:

```
import CommonCrypto
```

Comment: This won't work for a framework target. The error returned is: "Include of non-modular header inside framework module '<your_module>'".

Comment: @m_katsifarakis I don't know whether this helps but Xcode 10 makes CommonCrypto available for import in Swift without the need for a bridging header.

Comment: Yup, that's how I've done it too, but not all of my team can use it just yet.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't need to compile any file to using CommonCrypto, just import it in your project.

or using some wrapper in Swift, just like https://github.com/soffes/Crypto

Let's back to CommonCrypto file,Apple have released it's source code in https://opensource.apple.com/source/